# Uploading Static Resources to salesforce.com

Tags: javascript, salesforce

I am just going through salesforce.com development article and I found a task painful, that is uploading static files. I had found below solutions as of now

1. Eclipse plugin to convert it to resource files, and doing operations on it.
2. I can use either sublime text MavensMate plugin

I have gone through the articles of Eclipse plugin and adding some more files to the existing collection is again a big pain for me. I have gone through mavensmate plugin but still I did not understand much easiness in it.

He my Question is `What is the Web API provided by salesforce.com so that I can make Ajax request with user name and password and upload the zip files with my own interface.`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's more appropriate for salesforce.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to upload static resources during development, you can use Eclipse for that. It is described in [this article](http://fractastical.com/2010/05/12/uploading-static-resources-from-eclipse/).

If you want to communicate with salesforce through a web API, you should use [SOAP API](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/index_Left.htm) or [REST API](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_rest/index.htm). [Documentation](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_staticresource.htm) for static resources says:

> Encoded Data
>
> The API sends and receives the binary file data encoded as a base64 data type. Prior to creating a record, clients must encode the binary file data as base64. Upon receiving an API response, clients must decode the base64 data to binary (this conversion is usually handled for you by the SOAP client).

Answer (score 2):

The Salesforce.com API for creating/modifying Static Resources is the [Metadata API](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/index_Left.htm). The Metadata API is SOAP-only at this time.

PS - The MavensMate feature you mention is called ["Resource Bundles"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g4M5zr8Q8MY)